# Laravel 8 login route

Tags: php, laravel

> Invalid route action:
> [C:32:"Opis\Closure\SerializableClosure":213:{a:5:{s:3:"use";a:0:{}s:8:"function";s:47:"function
> () { return \view('auth.login'); }";s:5:"scope";s:37:"Illuminate\Routing\RouteFileRegistrar";s:4:"this";N;s:4:"self";s:32:"00000000642b658c000000002f9dd797";}}].

How can i solve this, if any one there

Comment: Remove any route cache file with `php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 1):

Try moving all your closure logic into controllers it worked for me!

Or try:

```
php artisan route:clear 

composer update
```